# Preserve history of file in git repo while moving to other folder

Tags: git

I have `file1.txt` in my git `repo`, the initial repo structure was

```
repo/
     file1.txt
     directory1/
```

`file1.txt` had two commits (when I tried using following command it showed two commits)

```
git log -p file1.txt
```

later I moved `file1.txt` to `directory1` using git command

```
git mv file1.txt directory1
```

then the new repo structure is

```
repo/

     directory1/file1.txt
```

but after moving that file, it does't show those two commits using

```
 git log -p directory1/file1.txt
```

Can anyone help how to preserve history while moving files like this, or there is some other way to move files?

Answer (score 3):

Git does not record moves explicitly (like for instance SVN does). Each commit is a snapshot of the entire state. So, it does not matter if you moved the file using `git mv A B` or moved it using `mv A B && git add A B`, or moved it in any other way and added this change -- the result will be identical.

Git instead provides tools to view the history in various ways. Whether or not a particular change was a rename is determined on-the-fly as the data is viewed.

Using the `--follow` option to `git log` will enable rename detection.

```
git log --follow -- path/to/file
```

Sometimes when a file is renamed, one might also change its contents. Depending on how much of the content has changed, rename detection might not work -- it becomes the question of whether it is a rename, or a deletion and an unrelated addition. To change how much of the file that needs to match for it to be considered a rename, use the `-M` option.

```
git log -M40% --follow -- path/to/file
```

The `-M` option also works with other commands such as `git diff` and `git show`.

There is also `-C` which is equivalent to `-M` except it detects copies.

If a file needs to be renamed and its contents also change a lot, a trick is to, if possible, do the rename and the content modification in separate commits. That way the rename will be detected without the need for tweaking.

More info at [man git-log](https://gitirc.eu/git-log.html), [man git-diff](https://gitirc.eu/git-diff.html), [man git-show](https://gitirc.eu/git-show.html).

Answer (score 1):

The history is preserved, `git log` just doesn't show it by default. You can use the `--follow` flag to track changes beyond renaming or moving the file:

```
$ git log --follow -p directory1/file1.txt
```

Comment: Using this command it shows but does't show on github history for that file as well